# Not able to import List from SharePoint 2013 to SharePoint 2010 site

Tags: sharepoint-2010, sharepoint-2013

I am trying to import list using the "save list as template" but not able to.

I am able to upload the SharePoint 2013 list template in SharePoint 2010 List template gallery, but when I try to create a list with it, SharePoint is not allowing me to do so and throws correlation Id error.

Is backward compatibility not provided for SharePoint 2010?

Thanks in advance

Comment: You should know that this cant be possible. Because there is different version of list template in SharePonint 2013 and SharePoint 2010.

Comment: Go through your own question in MSDN.
https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/7dbdaa90-267e-4eb2-844c-8e97028c52fe/not-able-to-import-list-from-sharepoint-2013-to-sharepoint-2010-site?forum=sharepointgeneral